# Angular2 ngIf dynamic change

Tags: angular

I am using `*ngIf` for an element

```
<div *ngFor="let el of elemenets>
  <div *ngIf="el.offsetTop < scrollTop">
         ....
  </div>
</div>
```

offsetTop represent the offsetTop of the div `*ngIf` condition is bound to.

What I do in component is I keep the pageYOffset in the variable e.g

```
class Test implements onInit{
  scrollTop:number = 0;
  ngOnInit{
    window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        this.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
        console.log(this.scrollTop)
    },true)
  }
}
```

It works when site gets loaded , but when I scroll up or down and change value of `scrollTop` variable it stays the same.

If I understood it correctly , `*ngIf` watch changes so when scrollTop variable changes it should  again evaluate condition, but it does not in my case.

Is there a solution to my problem or do I have to find different approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll)
scrollHandler(event) {
  this.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
   console.log(this.scrollTop)
}
```

or

```
class Test implements onInit{
  scrollTop:number = 0;
  ngOnInit{
    window.addEventListener('scroll',() => { // <== changed to arrow function to keep `.this`
        this.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
        console.log(this.scrollTop)
    },true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i wrote the question wrongly. The value of window.pageYOffset is stored inside variable and it does change value as i scroll down/up , but ngIf  evaluate condition only when page is loaded. It does not re - evaluate condition when the value of scrollTop variable changes when it should

Comment: Have you tried any of my suggestions? Even when the event handler is called, if `this` doesn't point to your component this doesn't help much.

Comment: yep , that worked! thanks,  but why the second or mine approach did not work as it should?

Comment: With `function(){` `this` will be where the function is actually called from, not your component instance. If my 2nd example doesn't work it might be a zone issue that `window.addEventListener` is not patched or that the `scroll` event somehow doesn't work with zone. You would probably need to invoke change detection manually for Angular to notice a change has happened.